# Extremely slow writing speed when inserting rows into Hive table using impyla

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, impala, impyla

I'm experiencing extremely slow writing speed when trying to insert rows into a partitioned Hive table using `impyla`.

This is an example of the code I wrote in python:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect

targets = ... # targets is a dictionary of objects of a specific class
yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
log_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
query = """
        INSERT INTO my_database.mytable
        PARTITION (year={year}, month={month}, day={day})
        VALUES ('{yesterday}', '{log_ts}', %s, %s, %s, 1, 1)
        """.format(yesterday=yesterday, log_ts=log_datetime,
                   year=yesterday.year, month=yesterday.month,
                   day=yesterday.day)
print(query)
rows = tuple([tuple([i.campaign, i.adgroup, i.adwordsid])
              for i in targets.values()])

connection = connect(host=os.environ["HADOOP_IP"],
                     port=10000,
                     user=os.environ["HADOOP_USER"],
                     password=os.environ["HADOOP_PASSWD"],
                     auth_mechanism="PLAIN")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict")
cursor.executemany(query, rows)
```

Interestingly, even though I'm launching an `executemany` command `impyla` still resolve it into multiple MapReduce jobs. In fact I can see as many MapReduce jobs launched as many tuples included in the tuple of tuples object I'm passing to the `impyla.executemany` method.

Do you see anything wrong? To give you an idea after more than an hour it wrote just 350 rows.

Comment: IMHO, running *INSERT* commands in Hive *(using the "transaction mode" and ORC files plus a background compaction process)* is about as efficient as driving to the mall with a bulldozer. Personally, I would use an _EXTERNAL_ table backed by text files, then use an HTTP client to connect to WebHDFS and "create" new text files. Or, "append" data to a single, global text file.

Comment: Can you argument a little more your answer @SamsonScharfrichter ? I'm not a Data Engineer so I'm not that familiar with the solution you suggested. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just create a Hive *EXTERNAL* table *STORED AS TEXTFILE* with *LOCATION '/some/hdfs/dir'*, then drop a couple of TXT files in that directory and run some SQL, then experiment with the HDFS command line `hdfs dfs -appendToFile`, then look into WebHDFS https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#APPEND *(note that the 2-step process is totally unnecessary, unless you use a very old and buggy HTTP client)*